# Advantage of !0 over boolean true

Tags: javascript

When i walk through minified file of javascript, i can see '!0' instead of boolean `true` and `!1` instead of boolean `false`.

- Is there any performance boost with it?
- Do you recommend to use this notation in normal javascript code?

Comment: !0 and !1 save a few keystrokes :)

Comment: @SilviuBurcea: This ain't about keystrokes. It's about saving bytes.

Comment: The second question is asking for an opinion. I'll answer it with a counter-question so you can answer it for yourself: do you want to maintain short code or readable code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's shorter (ie. less bytes) ... Minification is typically done to save bandwidth, not for execution performance.

Consider a JS file to have 500 `true` and 500 `false`:

- 2 bytes save for every `true`;
- 3 bytes save for every `false`;
- 2500  bytes saved for every request;
- That's almost 10M saved for every 10,000 requests.

This may not sound like much, but if you're big (millions of requests) this (together with other minification techniques) can add up quite a bit... It's not just bandwidth that counts, a server can support only so many open tcp connections at a time, so if your request is done 10ms faster, then we can serve more people with the same capacity.

**Edit**: Florian Schöffl [added a performance test](http://jsperf.com/not-0-vs-true); while there is *some* difference, it's only visible if we do *hundreds of millions* of tests, and even then it's *very* small. In other words: there is no measurable real-world performance difference, since the number of boolean tests even in large projects is much smaller (by several order of magnitude).

You should **never** type this in your JavaScript code manually; if you care about minification, use tools to do so. There are many good minification tools.

Answer (score 1):

There IS a difference in the performance. [See here](http://jsperf.com/not-0-vs-true) 
You can use this techniques if you want, but its worse for
human eyes to read and only like 0.15% faster, so i dont recomend it!

Comment: But a = !1 is slower than a = false

Comment: @FizerKhan: Insignificantly slower, yes. Who cares about a few million operations per second more or less when it's running at `~800.000.000` ops / second? It's not like you'll see the difference, even if you have a thousand booleans.

Comment: @FizerKhan: Surprisingly, `!1` is faster than `false` in some browsers - see Florian's jsperf link.  (Though the difference is negligible.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like !0 just a shortest equivalent of true.